# Resolving component from class name in Angular 4

Tags: angular

Is it possible to resolve a component from string?

Previously in Angular 2, we are able to do this [see here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Aaj2oHf8r4J0tR7qJU5Z?p=preview). However, in Angular 4, the same method will throw error.

```
private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver

var factories = Array.from(this.resolver['_factories'].keys());
var factoryClass = <Type<any>>factories.find((x: any) => x.name === this.comp);
const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(factoryClass);
const compRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(factory);
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because 'ComponentFactoryResolver' has no index signature

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might be relying on an implementation detail. However, to get around the error, you can explicitly cast the type to `any` in order to access the indexer.  Assuming there is a `_factories` property, this should work:

```
var factories = Array.from((<any>this.resolver)['_factories'].keys());
```

Comment: it's not works on angular 11.